# Activity Management in distributed architecture using AWS SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-swf

I have two servers(EC2 instances). In one server(server 1) i have 3 Batch and on another(server 2) i have 4 Batch. Now, one of the batch in server 2 needs to be executed only after the successful execution of a batch in server 1.

**updated**

```
    Promise<Void> r12 = null
    new TryCatchFinally(){

    // First server job sequencing
    Promise<Void> r11 = client1.b1();
    r12 = client1.b2(r11);
    Promise<Void> r13 = client1.b3(r12);
    Promise<Void> r14 = client1.b4(r13);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Failed to execute commands in server 1");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doFinally() throws Throwable {
    // cleanup
    }       
    }
    new TryCatchFinally(){

    // Second server job sequencing
    Promise<Void> r21 = client2.b1();
    // Will execute only when both parameters are ready
    Promise<Void> r22 = client2.b2(r21, r12);
    Promise<Void> r23 = client2.b3(r22);
    Promise<Void> r24 = client2.b4(r23);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Failed to execute commands in server 2");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doFinally() throws Throwable {
    // cleanup
    }       
    }
```

Any of the activity in any server can throw any custom exception. But the execution of any activity in a sever should not be cancelled because of exception thrown by activity in another server. Activity in a server should only be cancelled in case one of the activity in its own server throws any exception. (Dependent activity should also gets cancelled out irrespective of server if the activity on which it is dependent fails or throw any exception). For this what I did is wrapped it into two separate try catch block.

how to terminate the Workflow Execution if the activity of server 1 and server 2 both throws any exception or fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each Spring Batch execution into a SWF activity and then use SWF decider to sequence these activities. See [AWS Flow Framework](http://aws.amazon.com/swf/details/flow/) documentation and [recipes](http://aws.amazon.com/code/2535278400103493) for more info.

*Added after reading the updated description of the problem:*

You can use Promises to sequence activities in any way. So in your case I would do something like:

```
// First server job sequencing
Promise<Void> r11 = client1.b1();
Promise<Void> r12 = client1.b2(r11);
Promise<Void> r13 = client1.b3(r12);
Promise<Void> r14 = client1.b4(r13);

// Second server job sequencing
Promise<Void> r21 = client2.b1();
// Will execute only when both parameters are ready
Promise<Void> r22 = client2.b2(r21, r12);
Promise<Void> r23 = client2.b3(r22);
Promise<Void> r24 = client2.b4(r23);
```

If any of the activities throws an exception it would cancel all outstanding activities and fail the workflow unless the exception is explicitly catched and handled using [TryCatchFinally](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/TryCatchFinally.html). Activity that wasn't started (for example because it is waiting for its parameters of type Promise become ready) is cancelled immediately. An activity that is  executing should explicitly handle cancellation. See "Activity Heartbeat" section from [Error Handling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/errorhandling.html#test.cancellation.resources) page of the [AWS Flow Framework Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/welcome.html) for more info.

*Added the error handling part:*

You wrap the part that shouldn't affect other parts of the worklfow in the TryCatch. So in this example any client2 activity throwing an exception cancels all future client2 activities, but not activities called on client1 as exception is not thrown into its scope.

```
// First server job sequencing
Promise<Void> r11 = client1.b1();
final Promise<Void> r12 = client1.b2(r11);
Promise<Void> r13 = client1.b3(r12);
Promise<Void> r14 = client1.b4(r13);

new TryCatch(){

  @Override
  protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
    // Second server job sequencing
    Promise<Void> r21 = client2.b1();
    // Will execute only when both parameters are ready
    Promise<Void> r22 = client2.b2(r21, r12);
    Promise<Void> r23 = client2.b3(r22);
    Promise<Void> r24 = client2.b4(r23);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
    // Handle exception without rethrowing it.
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly? SWF allows to execute activities in any sequence. So you just schedule activity1 and after it completes you schedule activity2. There is no need to send any "notification" as SWF takes care of all necessary low level plumbing. Activities are scheduled and polled by workers using "task lists". So to route activity1 and activity2 to different EC2 instances they have to use different task lists.

Comment: Thank you.. Is there any way to ensure that the jobs that are not dependent on another server doesn't get cancelled out because of any exception thrown by another server's job?

Comment: Yes, wrap the activities that should be cancelled together in a TryCatch and handle the exception without rethrowing it. See JavaDoc of the TryCatchFinally for more info on exception handling.

Comment: Thank you.. How to terminate the Workflow Execution? Also how can I remove the stack trace and display custom message if there is any custom exception.

Comment: Maxim... I am facing issue with SWF cron. I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019926/executing-workflow-using-aws-swf-cron. I will be very much thankful to you if you can provide me the solution.