# Executing Workflow using AWS SWF Cron

Tags: amazon-swf

I want to execute my workflow at a specified time daily(say at 10 am JST) using AWS SWF cron. In the sample program in AWS SDK I find that activities can be scheduled using SWF cron. But how to schedule a workflow using AWS SWF cron. I am very much new to this SWF cron. Any suggestion is highly appreciated

**Activities Class:**

```
public class SampleActivitiesImpl implements SampleActivities{

    @Override
    public Integer testAct1() {
        System.out.println("Activity 1 ---->Start");
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer testAct2() {
        System.out.println("Activity 2 ---->Start");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Workflow Class:**

```
public class MyWorkflowImpl implements MyWorkflow{

    private SampleActivitiesClient client = new SampleActivitiesClientImpl();

    @Override
    public void executeActivity() {

        client.testAct1();
        client.testAct2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't schedule the cron workflow as it should be always running. 
BTW your sample code is just going to execute both activities in parallel without any scheduling.

Comment: Can we create a child workflow and schedule it using parent workflow? If so then, a sample code snippet would be really helpful

Comment: You can schedule an execution of any workflow code including a child workflow invocation. Just use the cron workflow example and replace the activity invocation with a child workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Look into scheduled events in Lambda. Will be the easiest way to achieve that.